# Missing HDRI when shading

Tags: shaders

We set up Blender on my wife's laptop, and everything works nice so far but the Shader tab has obviously a problem with the HDRI Settings, down below I've uploaded a screenshot, has anyone had this issue already and know a solution for that?

If I open up Blender it has no HDRI selected and no light at all. I managed to make a downloaded HDRI working but the shader ball below stays black all the time, no matter what I change.

I also thought it might be a problem with her graphics or blender itself so I decided to re-install blender, but that doesnt change anything, and then i Re-installed graphic drivers to make sure it's not the graphics. But the ball still remains black...

Is it maybe a bug that it doesnt show up correctly?

[image]

Comment: It's likely related to not fully supported GPU of that laptop, you might [edit] the post with more informaion. Aside from that as HDRi seems to be displayed correctly and if it's rotatated when you rotate the viewport it's not a big problem if only that shading ball is black

Comment: Yeah, looks like its not supported. -.- Damn...then we have to Upgrade her Workstation earlier than she thought ^^.... But thx 4 the help :-)